# Toggle iPad Cover Lock/Unlock setting for smart cover

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically set the iPad Cover Lock/Unlock toggle that shows up when a smart cover is attached to an iPad?

My goal is to make it so that the iPad will not go into standby mode while the app is running. I've found I can disable the auto-lock feature using

`[[ UIApplication sharedApplication ] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES ]`

However if the iPad is equipped with a smart cover closing the cover will put the iPad into standby mode.

This is for an enterprise application, so approval for the app store isn't a concern (undocumented API's are fine)

Answer (score 0):

AppStore apps have no access to change user settings of the OS, at least through any allowed/public method by Apple. If you submit to AppStore, I guess the app will be rejected.

Comment: Based off my ability to disable the auto-lock user setting (and change the brightness settings) I don't believe that this is correct. Also even if there is a method that isn't allowed by Apple it wouldn't be a problem in my case.

Comment: Is this a non AppStore app? If it's not, I'm curious for the solution.

Comment: Yes - it's for enterprise distribution so it won't need to be approved by Apple.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry for not having asked before. Edited the answer.